# How do you derive a Lagrangian equation for motion for any arbitrary number of energies?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Suppose you have a rubber ball moving in space, it has kinetic energy. Now, it enters Earth's gravitational field, so we see it must have potential energy as well. But wait, as the ball accelerates down to Earth, it begins to squish into itself, it has elastic energy too! Oh no, the ball is heating up and oxidizing in the atmosphere, not only changing its mass but creating random explosions at its surface that propel it in different directions, it had chemical potential energy all along! What!? The enormous friction with the atmosphere charged its surface!? Now it's deflecting towards that thunderstorm cloud!!

While all this energy is still conserved from the proper system consideration, clearly there's more to classical systems than simply kinetic and gravitational potential energy, so how do you derive Euler-Lagrangian equation of motion when you need more than just kinetic and potential energy? I assume for something like spontaneous chemical reactions you can use some kind of Heaviside step function to indicate a change from one type of energy to the next.

Comment: Put other potential terms in. This will make the equations of motion more complicated. So take out the potential terms that are insignificant.

Comment: Except how do you know all other possible energies are "potential" terms? Kinetic energy is it's own unique energy, why not others?

Comment: Even if you could do this (construct a Lagrangian for an arbitrarily complex situation) there's the problem of deriving a useful solution from it.  We break problems up into phases and use perturbation and other methods precisely because it lets us get to a useful solution.  Writing a super complex equation gets us nothing except an intractable mathematical problem.